# A two line caption for a longtable?

Tags: captions, longtable

I am unable to have a two line caption as shown in the picture. Could someone help fixing the problem please? The MWE is given below:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0.9in,right=0.9in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{ppl}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}

    \noindent
    \begin{longtable}[t]{l l l}
        \caption*{\textbf{CAPTION}} \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Head 1} & \textbf{Head 2} & \textbf{Head 3} \\   
        \hline
        X1   & \quad A & \enspace B \\   
        X1   & \quad A & \enspace B \\   
        X1   & \quad A & \enspace B \\   
        X1   & \quad A & \enspace B \\   
        X1   & \quad A & \enspace B \\   
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
    \vspace{1mm}
    \centering{\textbf{Some text}}\\
    \scriptsize{(Some more text)}\\
    \scriptsize{(Target text is here)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do `\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}` rather than `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{ppl}`. The `[t]` option to `longtable` does nothing at all. Note also that `\centering` and `\scriptsize` are declarations, not commands that take an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need the package `caption` for this:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[oneside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0.9in,right=0.9in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}

    \begin{longtable}{lcl}
        \caption*{\textbf{CAPTION}\\\scriptsize (Target text is here)} \\
        \toprule
        \textbf{Head 1} & \textbf{Head 2} & \textbf{Head 3} \\   
        \midrule
        X1   &  A & \enspace B \\   
        X1   &  A & \enspace B \\   
        X1   &  A & \enspace B \\   
        X1   &  A & \enspace B \\   
        X1   &  A & \enspace B \\   
        \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}   

    \begin{center}
        \textbf{Some text}\\
        \scriptsize (Some more text)\\
        (Target text is here)
    \end{center}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Even if it is the OP's code, you should fix the obviously wrong usage of `\centering`.

Comment: @egreg thanks for pointing that out. I should not answer when in hurry.